# How to load tensorflow graph from memory address

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using the TensorFlow C++ API to load a graph from a file and execute it. Everything is working great, but I'd like to load the graph from memory rather than from a file (so that I can embed the graph into the binary for better portability). I have variables that reference both the binary data (as an unsigned char array) and the size of the data.

This how I am currently loading my graph.

```
GraphDef graph_def;
ReadBinaryProto(tensorflow::Env::Default(), "./graph.pb", &graph_def);
```

Feels like this should be simple but most of the discussion is about the python API. I did try looking for the source of `ReadBinaryProto` but wasn't able to find it in the tensorflow repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
GraphDef graph_def;
if (!graph_def.ParseFromArray(data, len)) {
    // Handle error
}
...
```

This is because `GraphDef` is a sub-class of `google::protobuf::MessageList`, and thus inherits [a variety of parsing methods](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#parsing)

Edit: Caveat: As of January 2017, the snippet above works only when the serialized graph is <64MB because of a [default protocol buffer setting](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream#CodedInputStream.SetTotalBytesLimit.details). For larger graphs, take inspiration from `ReadBinaryProto`s implementation

FWIW, the code for `ReadBinaryProto` is in [`tensorflow/core/platform/env.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a304537954a865752ad1b18461e6bd67b36082db/tensorflow/core/platform/env.cc#L321)

Comment: This was very helpful but only works if the graph is very small (<64MiB). Since my graph is much larger I was able to get it working by creating a `CodedInputStream` (just like is done in `ReadBinaryProto`). Can you update your answer with these details so others can have a full solution?

Comment: @JoshuaPiccari can u pls provide code to create CodedInputStream from memory address? Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaPiccari I tried to create the CodedInputStream from the buffer, but then it crashes in this call: proto->ParsePartialFromCodedStream( &coded_stream )
Do you have an idea why?