# How to load tensorflow graph from memory buffer

Tags: c++, tensorflow, graph, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to load a graph from the memory instead of a file for a portability purpose. So far what I tried is

```
tensorflow::GraphDef graph_def;
tensorflow::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream coded_stream( buffer, size );

// Total bytes hard limit / warning limit are set to 1GB and 512MB respectively.
//    coded_stream.SetTotalBytesLimit( 1024LL << 20 );

if( !proto->ParseFromCodedStream( &coded_stream ) || !coded_stream.ConsumedEntireMessage() )
{
    return tensorflow::errors::DataLoss( "Can't parse ", "memory", " as binary proto" );
}
```

buffer is a byte array( unsigned char* ) of the graph file 'graph.pb'. The code segfault at this line:

> proto->ParseFromCodedStream( &coded_stream )

i also tried `graph_def.ParseFromArray(data, len)` like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889453/how-to-load-tensorflow-graph-from-memory-address) or `graph_def.ParseFromString( stringData )` but it also crashes. Am I missing something? Thanks.

ps: I use Tensorflow 1.9 and protobuf 2.6.1 on Ubuntu16.04

**Edit**
Ok so far I've tried all possible Parse functions, and they all crash so I must have missed something very fundamental. The Parse functions I've tried are:

- ParseFromArray
- ParseFromString
- ParseFromCodedStream

First, I read the .pb file into a byte array as below:

```
std::ifstream is( "graph.pb", std::ios::binary );
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is), {});
```

Next, I convert it to a string:

```
string data(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
```

Finally, I call

```
graph_def.ParseFromString( data )
```

which crashes, and the same for `ParseFromArray()`. The annoying part is it crashes instead of returning an error, which makes me think I must have missed something fundamental.

Comment: `ParseFromArray` crashes, with which error?

Comment: Hi @Stefan, it segfaults in the CreateMessage() function as below:

    tensorflow::GraphDef* google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<tensorflow::GraphDef>() at 0x7fffc48e2ff1 
    google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromArray() at 0x7fffbe3b5038

Comment: What's the size of the graph? did you notice to the commented part in the code?

Comment: @Meisam I have 2 files, one is 19.2MB, and one is 196.5MB. and it failed with both files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it crashes is because of the mismatch between the **protobuf** runtime library version installed on the system and the version the code is linked with. In particular, this is the error:

```
This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.6.1.
```

I upgraded **protobuf** to version **3.5.0**, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert here, I've only used protobufs from python... but how did you encode that memory in the buffer? Are you sure it's encoded correctly for the [Coded Stream](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.coded_stream)? Coded Streams sound like an internal detail:

> Typically these classes will only be used internally by the protocol buffer library in order to encode and decode protocol buffers.

Have you tried the more basic/public ["SerializeToString", "ParseFromString", "SerializeToOstream", "ParseFromIstream"](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial#reading-a-message) methods?

Comment: Hi @mdaoust the .pb file can be loaded by the function ReadBinaryProto, so I assume it can be loaded by ParseFromString, however it doesn't work either.